# Bash percentage used not using bc

Tags: bash, awk, bc

I'm trying to work out a percentage with out using bc as this isn't installed on the clients server and they won't allow it to be.

Normally I would do `echo 100/$limit*$usage | bc -l`

eg:

`echo 100/32212254720*213779238 | bc -l`

Which returns a value of `.00001271565755207680`

This is then rounded using `printf "%.0f\n" .66365810111130947790` which returns 0

I'm trying to do this with awk.

`awk "BEGIN {print (100/$limit*$usage)}"`

eg:
`awk "BEGIN {print (100/32212254720*4096)}"`

Which returns `1.27157e-05` and when rounded using `printf "%.0f\n" 1.27157e-05` also returns 0

So both do seem to be working but is awk used correctly and why does it return 1.27157e-05 and not .00001271565755207680?

Comment: `printf` is largely the same in `awk`. You just need to make sense of your quoting and variable. I would do: `awk -v limit="$limit" -v usage="$usage" 'BEGIN {printf "%0.0f\n", (100/limit*usage)}'`

Comment: @dawg thanks I looked into it and came up with the same